# How to save Shift + PrintScr Screenshots to Desktop automatically?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I frequently use Screenshot tools which automatically get invoked by keyboard shortcut `Shift + PrintScr`. I have changed that keyboard shortcut to `Shift + F1` because F9 to Program keys of my 4-5 years old Kinesis advantage keyboard have a circuit trouble.

Anyway, now these screenshots gets automatically saved to my `Home` folder. I want to change that to automatically save to `Desktop`.

Automatically saving to `Desktop` give me opportunity to `Trash` useless screenshots on start-up at-least everyday.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`gnome-sccreenshot`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot), you can set the default 'save-to' directory with dconf or gsettings.

```
# gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "[path-to-directory]"

MyDesktopFolder=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "$MyDesktopFolder"
```

Then restart gnome shell
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` then <kbd>↵</kbd>.

Comment: I have done it using dconf editor org -> gnome -> gnome-screenshot -> auto-save-directory Current value '/home/neo/Desktop' but it still save screenshots in /home/neo.

Comment: did you restart gnome ?

Comment: No, can you please include that in your answer?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal : Edit done